# How to install Spark, Hadoop on EMR using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, terraform

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = "emr-test-arn"
  release_label = "emr-4.6.0"
  applications  = ["Spark", "Hadoop"]
```

Mentioning `"Spark", "Hadoop"` in `applications` parameter as shown above - will that install Hadoop and Spark on the EMR?

Or does it just `"prepare"` the cluster in some way to work with Hadoop and Spark (and we should perform additional steps to install Hadoop and Spark on the EMR cluster)?

Comment: They will be on the emr cluster ready to use. The script does not work? You would have to show all of it and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the official docs with examples like below. It works fine
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/emr_cluster

```
resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = "emr-test-arn"
  release_label = "emr-4.6.0"
  applications  = ["Spark"]

  additional_info = <<EOF
{
  "instanceAwsClientConfiguration": {
    "proxyPort": 8099,
    "proxyHost": "myproxy.example.com"
  }
}
EOF

  termination_protection            = false
  keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps = true

  ec2_attributes {
    subnet_id                         = aws_subnet.main.id
    emr_managed_master_security_group = aws_security_group.sg.id
    emr_managed_slave_security_group  = aws_security_group.sg.id
    instance_profile                  = aws_iam_instance_profile.emr_profile.arn
  }

  master_instance_group {
    instance_type = "m4.large"
  }

  core_instance_group {
    instance_type  = "c4.large"
    instance_count = 1

    ebs_config {
      size                 = "40"
      type                 = "gp2"
      volumes_per_instance = 1
    }

    bid_price = "0.30"

    autoscaling_policy = <<EOF
{
"Constraints": {
  "MinCapacity": 1,
  "MaxCapacity": 2
},
"Rules": [
  {
    "Name": "ScaleOutMemoryPercentage",
    "Description": "Scale out if YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage is less than 15",
    "Action": {
      "SimpleScalingPolicyConfiguration": {
        "AdjustmentType": "CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY",
        "ScalingAdjustment": 1,
        "CoolDown": 300
      }
    },
    "Trigger": {
      "CloudWatchAlarmDefinition": {
        "ComparisonOperator": "LESS_THAN",
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "MetricName": "YARNMemoryAvailablePercentage",
        "Namespace": "AWS/ElasticMapReduce",
        "Period": 300,
        "Statistic": "AVERAGE",
        "Threshold": 15.0,
        "Unit": "PERCENT"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
EOF
  }

  ebs_root_volume_size = 100

  tags = {
    role = "rolename"
    env  = "env"
  }

  bootstrap_action {
    path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if"
    name = "runif"
    args = ["instance.isMaster=true", "echo running on master node"]
  }

  configurations_json = <<EOF
  [
    {
      "Classification": "hadoop-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    },
    {
      "Classification": "spark-env",
      "Configurations": [
        {
          "Classification": "export",
          "Properties": {
            "JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "Properties": {}
    }
  ]
EOF

  service_role = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.arn
}
```